# How to align the columns themselves, not the content in them to left in a table

Tags: html, css

I am making a table, where I don't know the number of columns beforehand. Since the first column is wider than the others, I know the width for it. I would like to make the other columns smaller, with same width for each column. How can I make a table layout, where if I have 3 columns for example, first one the wider, and the others smaller, how can I align these columns, so that they take up the space in the table to the left, and leave the left space on the right.

So, the layout would look something like this:

```
column1           |  column2 | column3
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
value1            |        2 |       3  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, I am not sure how to achieve this, since I am also aligning the content of all the columns but the first one to the right. And I need the last column to take the whole space of the table, because I should show the bottom border all the way to the end of the table layout.

I only have very little css for this table so far:

```
.table {
  tr {
    td:last-child {
      border-left: dashed 2px gray;
    }
    td {
      text-align: right;
    }

    td:first-child {
      text-align: left;
      width: 40%;
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how can I achieve the desired layout?

Comment: Most of this is possible but equalising width of intermediate columns is **not** using a table layout AFAIK.

Comment: You specify width for 1st and 2nd column and the 3rd column will fill the rest of the space.

Comment: @NawedKhan **The number of columns is not known.**

Comment: @NawedKhan but, then the content of the 3rd column would be moved all the way to the right, and that is not what I want, how can I make this so that the content appears to be the same width of the 2nd column?

Comment: You  can use `calc()` function in css

Comment: @Ramesh No you can't if the number of columns is not known.

Comment: @Paulie_D oops.. I missed that part. You are right with pure Html and CSS it is not possible. With client side script you can specify the column widths of intermediate columns like (100-FirstColumnWidth) / NumOfColumns and then add a blank column at the end with no width defined so it will fill the rest of the space. The problem with this unknown-column-count is that what if there are 100 columns? each column get less than 1% ????

Comment: Even if the number of columns was known...there is **no CSS method** of aligning the text in which the OP requires since they do no share a parent.

Comment: Can the columns have a fixed width? I provided a solution that looks like the layout you expect, let me know if this works for you or you need the width to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using flex and a meta element ::after for the last col like this:

```css
.mytable {
  width: 100%;  
}

tr {
    display: flex;    
}

tr:after {  
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;  
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}
  
td {
  width: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  text-align: right;    
}

td:first-child {  
  width: 200px;
  border-left: 0;      
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<h3>A table with more columns also works:</h3>

<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
    <td>column4</td>
    <td>column5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not resolve the text alignment issue...which is not solvable with CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D I add an example with more columns and as you can see it equalise multiple intermediate columns. Regarding the alignment, I see that my table looks like the layout that the OP expects, aligning the 1st col to the right and the rest to the left.

Comment: Actually you haven't equalised the *intermediate* columns, just not the first one. Also, check the text alignment again - the "5" texts are not aligned....and that's not solvable with CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D I modified my snippet, I used a meta :after for the last col, which solved the problem of the alignment using only css.

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve this by setting the `width` of the first td to `100%`. It will use all the available space. You can guarantee a minimum width to the other tds using some `min-width`

Comment: This does not resolve the issue of intermediate columns having the **same width** - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jeQMeR

Comment: But, then the other columns would be aligned to the right, and I wrote in the question that that is not what I want.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood, then. I thought this was what you were trying to achieve: https://codepen.io/raphaelaleixo/pen/WaYobq